# Carousel not working inside modal of bootstrap in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

This is my carousal.

```
<div class="modal-body mbody">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate> 
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol> 

 <div class="carousel-inner">
 <asp:Repeater ID="repid" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <img alt="" style='height: 275px; width: 275px' src='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  </div>

  </div>

  </ContentTemplate>
  </div>
```

And this is my .cs part.I have included this event in the pageload.I mean the repeater is binded with database.

```
public void bindslide()
{
    //string str = Session["userid"].ToString();
    string str = "22";
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from mygallary where regId_img='" + str + "' ", sq.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    repid.DataSource = ds;
    repid.DataBind();

    sq.con.Dispose();
    sq.con.Close();

}
```

What happens is that the image are loaded side by side instead of sliding.Where did i go wrong?

**Edit**
This is what i am getting.

[image]

Comment: Can you view the HTML output and post that as well? I suspect the repeater, when rendered, is messing up the DOM in such a way that the CSS selectors used for the carousel aren't firing correctly.

Comment: OK i'll edit the post and display output.

Comment: What do you expect to happen here? Should they not sit side by side? We have no visibility of your styling or an example of how this carousel should function.

Comment: Arent carousel supposed to slide...if not why would i need to use carousel.If slide was not what i wanted i would have called  `asp:image` inside `modal-body`.

Comment: we still need to see your html output (not just how the browser renders it)

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean by `see your html output`

Comment: Could you change your edited output to show the HTML itself and not just the rendered HTML? Paste it in like code, not like HTML

Comment: What we mean by see your HTML output, is you know how the code you posted was indented four spaces and is displayed in a grey box? We want to see the HTML also indented four spaces and displayed in a grey box, not just seeing how it looks in your browser. Does that make sense?

Comment: What HTML you are talking about..its all the code I have.It works when i provide the image path manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You have `item` and `item active` class missing in your code.You can modify your repeater and add `<div class='item'>` and `<div class='item active'>` inside your `ItemTemplate` respectively.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repid" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div class="item" >
  <div class="item active">
   <asp:Image ID="imgId" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imgPath") %>' />
  </div>
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For more see https://unschoolingcode.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/using-carousal-to-display-image-slide-from-database-in-asp-net/

Comment: This is what I suggested 16 hours ago?

Comment: Yes but you forget to mention to include `item active` class without which it shows blank area.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-carousel--webdesign-7442 the contents of each carousel item should be wrapped with a `div` of class `item`. I'd start by amending your code to read:

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repid" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div class='item'>
           <img alt="" style='height: 275px; width: 275px' src='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' />
         </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work but you've been asked 3 times for the rendered html. Show that, and show the relevant styling. Better still, put your example into a jsfiddle, for example, where we can see all CSS, JS and HTML at play. Does this have a JS file it's dependent on? Are there any browser errors?

Comment: This is all i have done.yes i have all the required .js files setup and it works when i manually provide the image path.